# RaspberryPI with Windows 10 IoT Core can use Silverlight?

Tags: windows-iot, android

I would use Raspberry PI 2 Model B to stream a PPW web content. That content, alas, are streamed with Silverlight (simply using a browser), with an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.mediaset.premiumplay&hl=it), or with a [Windows app](https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/store/apps/premium-play/9wzdncrfj22x).

I had no luck with Raspbian (and several attempt with archon), so I've considered two idea:

- Install Android and use official Android App
- Install Windows 10 for IoT and use official Windows App

Could this resolve the issue? Some italian users have doing some test? Could Internet Explorer in Win10 IoT Core (still exist, or removed in place of Edge?) do the job? 
Is the Windows App compatible with Windows 10 IoT? It seems compatible with ARM but I don't know if can run on that OS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good answer for this problem.

First - Windows 10 IoT Core cannot use Silverlight due to no compatibility.

In response to question about ideas:

Android OS for Raspberry Pi is very slow and there is big chance that your app will not work as good as you want.

As for the second idea, currently there is no apps like Edge pre-installed on the Windows IoT Core and most of the apps from the Store cannot be installed. To install new app on Windows IoT Core you need to have installation files on your computer.

Comment: Android doesn't work well enough on the RPi for this to be a viable option.

Comment: You are right. I have not used Android on the RPi before.

Comment: I have not so many solutions. The most likely is try to retrieve appx from Windows Store app official app. And probably pray :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Silverlight is dead since three years at least , it is very very unlikely it will ever work on the Windows 10 IoT Core SKU.

Silverlight didn't even work on Windows 8 RT , but only on Windows 8 Home/Professional/Enterprise.

As usual, Silverlight on Windows 10 Home does work fine.

Comment: What about Windows app?

Comment: The Windows app will only work on Windows 10 Home/Professional/Enterprise and only on x86 processors , which both means your Raspberry can't run it

Comment: As supported processors it says: x86, x64, arm, neutral :|

Comment: Can you get the .appx file directly ? Windows 10 IoT Core has no HW acceleration on RPi anway ...